# What is this chip with top mark "UTREW"?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Can somebody please help to identify what kind of IC this is?  It is from a PetNet Smartfeeder v1. It has the top mark "UTREW". The company is no longer around.

[image: Chip in question]

[image: Zoomed out area of the chip in question]

Comment: Identification of components is greatly aided by context: What device is it in? What are the surrounding components? Please see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/627046/2028 for a good example of how to ask a component identification question.

Comment: I'm not coming up with matches for the top mark. I did find full images of the mainboard in the product at [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Petnet+SmartFeeder+SF10E+Motherboard+Replacement/114350), hoping for some detail on the components; no such luck. At first I thought it was an 8-pin SOIC, but based on the images, it may be an 8-pin VSSOP instead.

Comment: You may have better luck asking a [community that has access to working units](https://github.com/feedernet/petnet-feeder-service/issues/15) to measure and characterize the IC. Also there appears to be a chance you could obtain a replacement board from people who are frustrated by the [circumstances that appear to surround this device](https://www.businessinsider.com/what-happened-when-petnet-smart-pet-feeder-went-out-of-business-2021-6?op=1) and are just throwing it away.

Comment: Could you add measurements of the package? Especially the pitch. I tried to use the available pictures and the best I could come up with is a 0.5 mm pitch. The only 8 pin package I could find with that pitch is SC70-8, but the few devices that use this package, like the LT3491, have different markings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markings match with a [Skyworks (formerly Analogic) AAT3681AIJS-4.2-T1](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/472/AAT3681A_201883C-258415.pdf) Battery Charger. The pinout is also plausible since pin 6-8 are ground and they are connected in the picture.

[image]

I could only find a picture of the AAT3681AIJS-4.2-4-T1, but it shows the marking style matches as well.

[image]

(source: [taobao.com](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=67056462334))