# I can't find these ICs marked DK=H6G, AW=JFM

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, identification

What are the ICs with the markings in the photos?

[image: DK=H6G]

Comment: Before you ask a bunch of identification questions, please review this one to see a good example of what to do to maximize chances of a positive ID: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/627046/2028

Comment: @JYelton, I edited the photo, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top one is a [Richtek RT9193-30GB](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810121731_Richtek-Tech-RT9193-30GB_C50004.pdf) LDO regulator.

[image]

(Source: [dokumen.tips](https://dokumen.tips/documents/richtek-marking-code.html?page=1))

---

The bottom one is a [Richtek RT9161-50GV](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Richtek-Tech-RT9161-50GV_C130825.pdf) LDO regulator.

[image]

(Source: [dokumen.tips](https://dokumen.tips/documents/richtek-marking-code.html?page=1))

Comment: Thank you very much @nanash1