Component identification: 33XXX SOT23-6





U1 at Hanny HYL8212 or FX101L power supply boards, N channel MOSFET switching IC. First 2 numbers are always 33, I've seen 33P2L, 33P1X, and 33048

For an example of a really great component identification question, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/627046/2028. Perhaps you could add information and images to improve this.

Added some pictures

The pictures make it difficult to identify surrounding circuity, due to the pictures being out of focus. Can the quality of the pictures be improved?

Done, if something wrong pls reply

It's probably a SiFirst SF5533LGT PWM controller.

While it's hard to tell from your pictures how everything is connect, I think it roughly matches the typical application circuit.

The markings look similar as well on this photo from taobao.com:


Yep, seems that's it. Will check and respond. Thank you!
